# Как добавить автоматическое обновление формулы скрипта при изменении названия листа? Google таблицы

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть код скрипта, который копирует в ячейку название листа с помощью указания его порядкового номера

```
function getSheetName(num) {
var cellNumber = num-1;         
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[cellNumber].getSheetName();
}
```

Значения не обновляются автоматически, только после повторного написания формулы =getSheetName(1)

Answer (score 0):

Прямого действия нет. Вы можете:

- Подписаться на изменения файлов через Drive Activity API, проверять
  изменения и править
- Либо проверять по триггеру каждую минуту проверять изменения и править
- Либо через пользовательскую функцию вызывать внешний адрес (web app),
  который будет править

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заставить таблицу выполнить расчет через flush(): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=ru#flush
Или после копировании имени листа, так же в необходимую ячейку пропишите формулу  скриптом